# Why google smtp does not stops when sent a single . dot after new line character while inputing data

Tags: smtp

When I am trying to send mail to google smtp server at alt1.aspmx.l.google.com on port number 25 it behaves normal but when I enter data and press a single dot after new line it still does not stop accepting data and keep accepting.

====

Look at following conversation

**nc alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 25** 

*mx.google.com at your service*
**HELO ashish**
250 mx.google.com at your service
**MAIL FROM:info@server.com**
250 2.1.0 OK hn8si29938637igb.69
**RCPT TO:info2myname@gmail.com**
250 2.1.5 OK hn8si29938637igb.69
**DATA**
354 Go ahead hn8si29938637igb.69
**Header blah blah**
**This is ashish.**
**Now you should stop**
**.**
**.**

==============

I expect that server should ideally say 250 Ok after seeing a . but it doesn't

Am I making any mistake, I hope not because same sequence of command works well with other SMTP servers. Is there any special diff rule to mention end of data while using Google smtp ?? :(

Comment: ok ... Am I making any mistake. If not, why is not it working for me ?

Comment: On what OS are you? I tried your steps with putty. Which client are you using? Are you sending CRLF and not just LF (that is a config option in some terminal emulators)?

Comment: I am on Linux (Opensuse Linux 12.1) Connceting with netcat

Comment: Can you try with a plain telnet? I expect nc to send only LF (0xa( instead of CRLF (0xd 0xa)

Comment: ok thanx for mentioning what you think. You were correct rene, it was due to exact problem what u thought. I used nc again but this time to send CRLF I used Control-V then Return and Return again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the `openssl` client to do a TLS session.  I have the same problem with Google's smtp relay service.  instead of the dot in a single line I can do ctrl-D, at which point the client terminates with the word "DONE"... but I never get an e-mail

Comment: ah.  I need to call the client with `-crlf`

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but you may want to use nc -C